# How to fit logarithmic curve to data, in the least squares sense?

Tags: regression

How to fit logarithmic curve to data, in the least squares sense?

I have simple data of the type $(x,y)$, that is 2D.
I need to fit curve of the type: $y = c_1 + c_2\ln(x)$.
So I have the $x$'s and the $y$'s but I need to learn the $c_1$ and $c_2$ coefficients.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach is to replace all of your $x_i$ with $X_i=\ln(x_i)$ and then do usual linear regression with the $(X_i,y_i)$.

Comment: Which formulas can I use for linear regression fit? Are these ok? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingLogarithmic.html

Comment: @user2381422 Yes, note that those are just the regular linear regression formulas, with $\ln(x_i)$ replacing each instance of $x_i$.

Answer (score 8):

Your equation is: $a\ln(x) + b = y$.  So set up matrices like this with all your data:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\ln(x_0) & 1 \\
\ln(x_1) & 1 \\
 &... \\
\ln(x_n) & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
y_0  \\
y_1  \\
...  \\
y_n
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
In other words:

$$Ax = B$$

Where

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
\ln(x_0) & 1 \\
\ln(x_1) & 1 \\
 &... \\
\ln(x_n) & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
$$
x = \begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
and
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix} 
y_0  \\
y_1  \\
...  \\
y_n
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
Now solve for $x$ which are your coefficients.  But since the system is over-determined, you need to use the left pseudo inverse: $A^+ = (A^T A)^{-1} A^T$.  So the answer is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
\end{bmatrix} = (A^T A)^{-1} A^T B
$$

Here is some simple Python code with an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

TARGET_A = 2
TARGET_B = 3
N_POINTS = 20
MAX_X = 50
NOISE_A = 0.1
NOISE_B = 0.2

# create random data
xs = [np.random.uniform(MAX_X) for i in range(N_POINTS)]
ys = []
for i in range(N_POINTS):
    ys.append((TARGET_A + np.random.normal(scale=NOISE_A)) * np.log(xs[i]) + \
              TARGET_B + np.random.normal(scale=NOISE_B))

# plot raw data
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(xs, ys, color='b')

# do fit
tmp_A = []
tmp_B = []
for i in range(len(xs)):
    tmp_A.append([np.log(xs[i]), 1])
    tmp_B.append(ys[i])
B = np.matrix(tmp_B).T
A = np.matrix(tmp_A)
fit = (A.T * A).I * A.T * B
errors = B - A * fit
residual = np.linalg.norm(errors)

print "solution:"
print "%f log(x) + %f = y" % (fit[0], fit[1])
print "errors:"
print errors
print "residual:"
print residual

# plot fit
fit_x = range(1, MAX_X)
fit_y = [float(fit[0]) * np.log(x) + float(fit[1]) for x in fit_x]
plt.plot(fit_x, fit_y, color='k')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

[image: log fit]

Comment: Good contribution, although for statistical or econometric analysis I would say that spline interpolation could lead to overfitting, so in case the analysis is econometric-statistical related I would recommend fitting a regression over the square root of x, as it is described in another response on this question

Answer (score 1):

If such a fit is appropriate then it's done the same way a least-squares fit is done when you have $y=c_1+c_2 w$, but in place of the $w$s you put the values of $\ln x$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, as long as your functional form is linear in the parameters, you can do a linear least squares fit.  You could replace the $\ln x$ with any function, as long as all you care about is the multiplier in front.  Section 15.4 of [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html), like any other numerical analysis text, will tell you how.  Obsolete versions are free.